# Why is one code preferred over the other? Or does it matter

Tags: java

I was just wondering if one of these code are preferred over another.

For example:

```
boolean even;

if (number % 2 == 0)
   even = true;
else
   even = false;
```

alternate code:

```
boolean even = (number % 2 == 0);
```

I was thinking that one was perferred over the other because one is shorter, but I feel like the first code is easier to read (being a beginner). I just want to know the REAL answer as to why one is preferred over the other or even if one is preferred over the other?

Comment: For me, the latter is shorter and easier to read. This is almost based in personal opinion, though.

Comment: The second one is shorter and as clear as the first one. The first one has no advantage.

Comment: There is 0 reason why one is better than the other.  Both will be interpreted the same way by the compiler.  It's entirely a matter of preference.

Comment: That's what I was thinking that it was a matter of personal opinion, not one being better than the other. But I am scared that someone like my professor would think one should be used over the other because it is a better alternative.

Comment: While beginners will find the first one more readable, you'll find that with experience the second one is as readable and being a one-liner makes it my preferred one...

Comment: I find the 1st one confusing. If you are going to use a boolean variable, give it a boolean value straight off. I don't like `even = (number % 2 == ) ? true : false;` either. That might even be worse.

Comment: @LeeMeador there's nothing confusing in the former code =\. Again, this is personal opinion.

Comment: As everyone is saying, it's just a matter of personal taste. But I would personally use `{` and `}` to clearly delimitate the statements in the `if` and `else` clauses if I were to go with the first option. Using if-else without brackets is error-prone (also personal opinion).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am glad you find your opinion non-confusing. I do too. That's the way it works. I agree with Bartdude as well and would encourage beginners to learn to write in a way that more experienced folks will prefer.

Comment: I cringe every time I see %2 to detect even-ness. "boolean even = (number & 1) == 0" is cheaper and gets the job done :)

Comment: @Durandal If you have a decent compiler, it's not cheaper.  (Optimizing `number % 2` is one of the easier optimizations to implement.)  It's much better to encourage programmers to focus on what's readable.  And, for many algorithms especially those that deal with mathematical formulae, `number % 2` expresses mathematically what the writer is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ajb You have the common misconception that everything that is easily imaginable is also done by compilers. The results of (m%2^n) and (m&2^n-1) are *not generically interchangeable* in java, due to the definition of %-operators results for negative m. Its certainly possible for the special case of n=2, but the VM currently does not do this optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the second one, because you avoid a branch. In the first case, you have an `if-else` construction. This means you have a branch in your code. The second example has no branch **in the code** which improves readability.

As @Dev pointed out, when you compile the Java source code to bytecode, unfortunately it generates a branch.

Technically, the compiler could choose to do something like this in assembly:

```
TEST eax   ; test for zero of "number % 2"
PUSHF      ; push flag-registers to the stack
POP ebx    ; pop them into a register
SHR ebx,?? ; shift to the FZ flag
AND ebx,1  ; cancel out the other flags
```

However, this is only a possibility, which is most likely to be not the case.

Comment: +1. I agree with you Martijn. Thinking about performances, it is better to avoid a branch. I just thought about how these 2 pieces of code could be written using a low level language like assembler ... Anyway, it is possible that during the compilation some optimizations occur.

Comment: This answer makes so much sense and is simple! I now understand that avoiding branches will make an entire program much more short and easy to follow! I gave you the best answer and +1 :D THANKS!!!

Comment: Just a note about performance: I realize that this is Java and we're dealing with the JVM.  But for other languages that get compiled to native code: many machines do not have instructions that say "if some comparison relation is true then generate 1 else generate 0", so an expression like `even = (number % 2) == 0` will result in branches anyway.

Comment: @ajb Actually this statement does generate a branch in the JVM bytecode, the answer is fundamentally incorrect. The bytecode emitted (arguments omitted) is `irem; ifne; ...; goto;` which is most certainly a branch.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, these kinds of micro optimizations (which in this case isn't guaranteed anyway) are usually not worth sacrificing readability. The stronger case for the second option is readability, not the uncertain possibility that JIT will make it branchless.

Comment: @Dev Amen to that last.  If you add up all the microseconds that have ever been saved by programmers making these cycle-saving decisions, they don't add up to a fraction of the time wasted due to bugs caused by programmers sacrificing readability.

Comment: @ajb: I rephrased my answer to be more correct.